# How to go passwordless for a nologin user and SSH tunnel?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a user to be used exclusively to access a floating license via an SSH tunnel.

```
Match User myuser
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  ForceCommand /sbin/nologin
  PermitOpen localhost:55555
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
  PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

The user has a `.ssh` folder with the `authorized_keys` file containing the pubkey, both with `600` rights and the correct owner:group `myuser:myuser`

It still asks me for the password.

The command: `ssh -N -L 2222:localhost:55555 myuser@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -p 22`

**Is that possible? What should I do?**

Comment: Check the logs on the server.

Comment: I guess you're talking about `/var/log/secure`, there is nothing before I enter the password there. Then no much help to know why it doesn't use my key.

Comment: Hmm. better check the permissions on your home directory, .ssh directory and file. One of them may be wrong. 600 is certainly wrong for a directory.

Comment: Listen to Michael, the `.ssh` directory should be `700`, also, why keep the `PasswordAuthentication yes`?

Comment: How could I make that mistake.. `700` for `.ssh` solved the problem. Thanks @MichaelHampton ! I definitely asked here too quickly..

Comment: @NickW I still want to be able to use password if needed. (the global's is set to no)

Comment: 0 probs, was just curious!